Realm Device Sync Hangs on App Launch When Offline (React SDK)
After following instructions for Access a Synced Realm While Offline, it seems Realm is still trying to connect when my app launches and then hanging indefinitely on either a blank screen or a provided fallback view.
I have two object schemas in my realm. One is configured for asymmetric sync (one way) and the other for flexible sync (two way).
When the app has a network connection, the sync service works as expected. It's offline app launch that is crashing.
I've followed suggestions in similar questions linked below with no success:
mongoDB Forums question
stack overflow question
What I've tried:

Wipe app data
Launch app with network connection and login
Close the app and re-open offline


I've tried the code below with and without the initialSubscriptions configuration.

I've also tried the Access After Timeout with Background Sync configuration.


Neither of the above has altered the resulting behavior.
Expectation:
The app launches normally using the cached user and the local realm.
Result:
The app hangs indefinitely on the fallback component provided in the sync configuration. Network errors appear in the console.
Of note: the console.log message in the sync onError block never fires. Any ideas or suggestions would be super appreciated!
"expo": "~48.0.21",
"react": "18.2.0",
"realm": "^12.11.1",
"@realm/react": "^0.8.0",

const RealmWrapper = ({children}) => {

    const [syncError, setSyncError] = useState(null);
    const realmAccessBehavior = {
        type: OpenRealmBehaviorType.OpenImmediately,
    };

    return (
        <AppProvider id={APP_ID} logLevel={'trace'} logger={(level, message) => console.log(`[${level}]: ${message}`)}>
            <UserProvider fallback={LoginWrapper}>
                <RealmProvider
                    schema={[SurveyResults, SurveyDesign]}
                    fallback={<RealmLoading />}
                    sync={{
                        flexible: true,
                        existingRealmBehavior: realmAccessBehavior,
                        newRealmFileBehavior: realmAccessBehavior,
                        
                        onError: (_, error) => {
                            console.log("I'm In the sync error handler!");
                            setSyncError(error);               
                        },

                        initialSubscriptions: {
                            update(subs, realm) {
                            subs.add(realm.objects(SurveyDesign).filtered("name != nil"), {
                                name: "All Survey Designs",
                                behavior: WaitForSync.Never,
                            });
                            },
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    {children}
                </RealmProvider>
            </UserProvider>
        </AppProvider>

    );
}

 ERROR  [Realm.Sync.Client.Network - error] Failed to resolve 'ws.services.cloud.mongodb.com:443': Host not found (authoritative)

 ERROR  [Realm.App - error] App: request location failed (CustomError -1): request to https://...../location failed, reason: Network request failed

 ERROR  [Realm.App - error] App: refresh_access_token: ...... -> 0 ERROR: request to https://....../location failed, reason: Network request failed


Question needs a bit of clarity: I have two schemas in my realm - two schemas? Meaning two object models, and you're trying to use one set of objects for offline work and a different set for online work? And they have different configurations? Why?

Sure. There are two object models defined in the realm. SurveyDesign is configured for bi-directional sync with a flexible sync subscription. This is used to share user-reated designs between devices.
SurveyResults is configured for uni-directional (asymmetric) sync. This is used to send collected data to Atlas in their 'Data Ingest' mode.  I'd be happy to post the models if it would help clarify. Both of them are used offline and online. They also appear to be working as expected with one major exception:
Offline app launch.

I believe that AsymmetricObjects are only compatible with Sync'd Realms. e.g. Because Realm auto-discovers schema, trying to open a non-sync'd Realm without implicitly excluding the asymmetric object throws an error - which sounds like what's happening here. That object should be excluded by only passing a subset of your classes in the configuration.

That makes sense. I'm reading docs linked below and seeing "An object that is asymmetrically synced is not stored locally..." - which means that throwing an error when offline would be appropriate. I will test this theory out and report my results. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/js/realm-react/latest/types/Realm.BaseObjectSchema.html

Also, supporting this hypothesis: "asymmetric objects are incompatible with bi-directional Flexible Sync, Partition-Based Sync, or local Realm use." At https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/device-sdks/sdk/react-native/sync-data/stream-data-to-atlas/#open-a-realm

Yeah - I think that's the culprit. Flexible Sync Requires a Subscription... You cannot create a subscription for an AsymmetricObject in the "IMPORTANT". Note that's from the Swift docs but it likely applies everywhere. I see this The AsymmetricObject type is incompatible with non-synced realms. Kinda makes sense as an asymmetric object only feeds the server with data, not local

Thanks for the help! It seems like the docs could be clearer on this. The code above IS using a flexible synced realm. And the asymmetric object is NOT included in the subscription configuration.

The question states: "I have two object schemas in my realm..One asymmetric ... the other for flex" so are these the two objects? schema={[SurveyResults, SurveyDesign]}?

Yes, that is correct

So.... You have two objects SurveyResults and SurveyDesign. And One is configured for asymmetric sync but we don't know which one. But the asymmetric object is NOT included in the subscription configuration and then schema={[SurveyResults, SurveyDesign]} which includes both objects in the subscription configuration? Can you clarify?

See comment above for the clarification on how each object is configured: "There are two object models defined in the realm. SurveyDesign is configured for bi-directional sync with a flexible sync subscription. This is used to share user-reated designs between devices. SurveyResults is configured for uni-directional (asymmetric) sync. This is used to send collected data to Atlas in their 'Data Ingest' mode".

I recently removed SurveyResults, the object configured for asymmetric sync - and tested with only schema={[SurveyDesign]} with no change in behavior.

Well, this is at least part of the trouble SurveyResults is configured for uni-directional (asymmetric) sync because - Flexible Sync Requires a Subscription... You cannot create a subscription for an AsymmetricObject - but that's what the code is trying to do schema={[SurveyResults, SurveyDesign]}... sync={{ flexible: true,. There may be additional code involved that's also having an issue but based on the code in the question, that's the root cause.

The code follows the example described in the documentation for opening a realm with an asymmetric object:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/device-sdks/sdk/react-native/sync-data/stream-data-to-atlas/#open-a-realm
So, I don't think that is the issue. If it were, I would expect the behavior to have changed when removing the asymmetric object from the schema property: schema={[SurveyDesign]}
